# how to append all sub-list numbers after using max_cliques() on a graph object

Tags: r, igraph

I have a `igraph` object that I created with the following:

```
    g3 <- graph.data.frame(DF.WORK.EDGE, directed=TRUE, vertices=DF.WORK.VERTEX)
```

And I applied `max_cliques()`on that graph object using:

```
    print('max clique for prefer to work with measure is: ')
    max_cliques(g3)
```

Naturally I got a long list of different clique sub-lists:

[image]

The list goes on and on and I need find which node appears most frequently (the most overlap) so I know which node is in different sub-cliques.

If there is no add-hoc function to sum up the frequency for these values, can anyone advise me how to retrieve all sub-lists and concatenate them all in the same list? I am thinking about doing a summary table after that to see which number shows up the most among all sub-lists. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `unlist` and `table` the `cliques`

```
set.seed(8675309) ##Sets the random number generator so that results are exactly reproducible.
g <- graph_from_edgelist(matrix(sample(LETTERS[1:10], 50, replace=T), ncol = 2), directed = FALSE) ##made a random graph
cliques <- max_cliques(g) ##Find maximal cliques

#cliques is a list of vectors containing nodes
#unlist turns the list into one vector, 
#a side effect of unlist is that the node ID is returned not the node
#name (in this case A-J) so we use the names function to grab the node names. 
#Lastly table tabulates the data, in this case counts the instances of each node in the vector. table could be replaced by tapply, or any other number of function.
nodeCliques <- table(names(unlist(cliques)))
#To get the nodes that are in the most cliques we subset the table based on the max number of cliques the nodes are in.
nodeCliques[which(nodeCliques==max(nodeCliques))]
# H I 
# 4 4
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this is concise and helpful! Would you mind explain a bit how `nodeCliques <- table(names(unlist(cliques)))` works?  broke it down bit by bit, but didn't get the logic about how it works.

Comment: thank you so much, this is a very thorough explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Let's make 10 random cliques:

```r
set.seed(42)
n_cliques <- 10
clique_sizes <- sample(x = 20, size = n_cliques)
x <- lapply(seq_along(clique_sizes), function(i) {
  sample(x = 50, clique_sizes[i]) 
})
x[1:3]
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] 23 36 45 13 22 43 44  6 20 50 37 48 38 49  3 18 14 30 15
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1] 42 37 39 19 32  1 49 45  9 38 25 15 17  2 36 16 33 30
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 32 48 30 16 47 18
```

Put them into a dataframe:

```r
d <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) {
  data.frame(
    clique = i,
    vertex = x[[i]]
  )
}))
head(d)
#>   clique vertex
#> 1      1     23
#> 2      1     36
#> 3      1     45
#> 4      1     13
#> 5      1     22
#> 6      1     43
```

Vertex 30 appears in 7 cliques:

```r
sort(table(d$vertex), decreasing = TRUE)[1:10]
#> 
#> 30  1 32 36 38 37 50  8 11 14 
#>  7  5  5  5  5  4  4  3  3  3
```

These are the 7 cliques:

```r
subset(d, vertex == 30)$clique
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 6 7 9
```

Comment: May I know what does the x=50 here mean, in `sample(x = 50, clique_sizes[i]) `?

Comment: It means that I want to sample `clique_sizes[i]` numbers from the interval `1:50`.

See more details at:
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sample.html

Also consider running the code to see what happens.